# What is the purpose of using --save-exact

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Want to know the use of `-exact` with `--save`

```
npm i typescript@3.4 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Comment: So did you read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install?

Comment: I agree with the above comment: questions that can easily be answered by consulting the documents shouldn't be in SO

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When using `save=true`, `npm install` will automatically add the package into package.json without the need of using `npm install --save` every time you run the command. `save-exact=true` will make sure that no sliding versions (with `~` or `^` ) will be installed.

reference [for more information click here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-install-npm-packages-as-saveexact)

or please go through this https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Just sharing... yarn alternative for this is:      yarn add pakcage_name -E

Answer (score 100):

For example, I use `--save-exact` when I manage projects with `webpack`.

As you know, when you install a package like `npm install --save-dev webpack` for example, our `package.json` will add something like:

```bash
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
}
```

###### What does it mean?

When you delete your `node_modules` folder and you run `npm install`, the versions of the installed packages could get updated when higher ones are available and that can potentially break your application.

For example from `5.1.3` maybe the package is going to uptade to `5.1.8`

So, the `--save-exact` will generate the next `package.json` code

```bash
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "5.1.3",
}
```

Whithout the `^` prefix to the version of the package, the installed version will be always the same as specified (here, Webpack  version `5.1.3`).

More reference here about semantic version with NPM:

- [About semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#example)

Comment: You say you use `--save-exact` to install webpack and [esbuild recommends the flag as well](https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#install-esbuild). Is this flag somehow suited to bundlers? If so, why?

Comment: @timakro, I gave an example using webpack, you can use the `--save-exact` with any package you think could break your application when its version would change

Comment: You can delete `node_modules` and the exact version will be re-installed thanks to the `package-lock.json` file. It's`npm update` that will install a newer version (within range). Adding `--save-exact` prevents this.